# Как сделать автоматическое переключение на следующий Input type=radio через определенный отрезок времени?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть три `input type="radio"`, нужно что бы они переключались по очереди через определенное время (3-5 сек) по кругу.

```
 <div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">    
    <label for="apple">apple</label>    
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
    <label for="banana">banana</label> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Вам нужен совет или человек который напишет все за вас? Если первое, то используйте setInterval(function(){}, 3000), если второе, то вы ошиблись сайтом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарно https://jsfiddle.net/w2svuf1c/

```css
$inputs = $('input');

setInterval(function(){

    $next = $inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');

    if ($next.length) $next.prop('checked', true);
    else $inputs.first().prop('checked', true);


}, 3000);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">    
    <label for="apple">apple</label>    
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
    <label for="banana">banana</label> 
 </div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы применялось только к диву class="slider"?

Comment: @DenisKorytkin `$inputs = $('.slider').find('input');`

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает, так как хотел